# Need to pass argument in href method

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I am working on a web application to show some data graphically using spring framework. In my code I am trying to call a javascript method from href tag of html. Problem is i can't pass argument to that method.

my html snippet is as below where i call the method.

```
<a href="javascript:getLimitHistory(${limitData.operatorCode})" th:text="${limitData.operatorCode}"></a>
```

and javascript method as follow

```
function getLimitHistory(opcode){
    console.log("Getting limit history for opcode: "+opcode);
}
```

Note that ***limitData.operatorCode*** is a thymeleaf variable and it has value **'S47648'** that i want to pass as argument to the method. But when press on that href item i am getting some error saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list            VM382:1

I hope somebody will help me here.

I wonder why nobody in the internet faced this problem before.

Comment: This error usually means there's something wrong with how the JS function is being called, so I would check the value of your thymeleaf variable to make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: You might need to enclose `${limitData.operatorCode}` in single quotes...

Comment: @AndroidNoobie
The value of limitData.operatorCode is a string like S47648

Comment: Pass ${limitData.operatorCode} in single quotes.

Comment: @Nick has a point, you might need to enclose it in single quotes or escape it.

Comment: Passing  ${limitData.operatorCode} in single quotes makes the argument '${limitData.operatorCode}' as string. But i want the value(S47648) as argument.

Comment: if you change your argument to `'${limitData.operatorCode}'`, you will still receive as `value(S47648) ` at receiving end.

Comment: @YoManTaMero
Sorry. But i am getting
"Getting limit history for opcode: ${limitData.operatorCode}" in javascript console

Do i have to change in javascript method for this ?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
<a th:href="javascript:getLimitHistory(${limitData.operatorCode})" 
 th:text="${limitData.operatorCode}"></a>
```

> Need to use th:* prefix. Once templates are compiled, all th:* tags will be disappeared.

Docs: 
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart